# How to get seo friendly urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How to get seo friendly urls for this

`mysite.com/list.php?place=japan&checkin=04%2F18%2F2012&checkout=04%2F20%2F2012&numberOfRooms=1&room-0-adult-total=2&room-0-child-total=0&x=105&y=23`

as

```
mysite.com/japan/
```

I tried like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /list.php?place=$1
```

But apache is nt rewriting and am sure that apache mod_rewrite is ON.
Can anyone sort it out lease

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just add `PT` and `L` as flags like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /list.php?place=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

You could then write your URL like `mysite.com/japan/` and it gets internally processed like `/list.php?place=japan` but all other query parameters are lost.

If you want to attach other parameters like checkin, checkout, etc. you could append them like this when setting the QSA-flag like I did in the rule. An URL with all arguments would then look like this:

```
mysite.com/japan/?checkin=04%2F18%2F2012&checkout=04%2F20%2F2012&numberOfRooms=1&room-0-adult-total=2&room-0-child-total=0&x=105&y=23
```